# How to change terminal screen size/resolution on Ubuntu 19.04 Server with VirtualBox?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, display-resolution

I installed Ubuntu Server 19.04 from VirtualBox on Windows Host.
I have a terminal screen 800x600.
VirtualBox does not provide me an option to change resolution.

How do I change the terminal resolution?

Tried:

1)  Downloaded VirtualBox Guest Additions from virtualbox.org, mounted media, and installed.

2)  sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso

Wonder if the problem is because it's the Server version, and there's no graphic interface or X11.

Guest Additions installed:

$lsmod | grep vboxguest

vboxguest     331776     1

Looks like GRUB might have something to do with it.

Looks like I need a *graphical* terminal.

Comment: Similar to being able to use Fullscreen, you need to install [Guest Additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-a-virtualbox-vm).

Comment: You may also need to boost Video Memory in your [VM Video Memory Settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bKzL.png)

Comment: Looks like this has to do with GRUB.